# Rewrite_tag filter plugin is not working properly when trying with latest Fluentbit Image version

Tags: fluent-bit, fluent-bit-rewrite-tag

I am using fluentbit with ecs - rewrite_tag filter plugin to differentiate both access and application logs but it is not working when i am trying with latest version of fluentbit image and working properly as expected when trying with old version of fluentbit.

Is there any plugin corrections while using latest version image or any issue ?